# How to cancel message sending in TTMessageController?

Tags: objective-c, three20

I use [**TTMessageController**](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php) to have a view similiar to the sms composer of iOS. The reference describes a method to cancel the composer which would close its modal view.

> ```
> - (BOOL) messageShouldCancel
> ```
>
> Determines if the message should cancel without confirming with the
>   user.

But I want to abort the sending of the message and leave the composer open. I could not find any method in the [reference](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php) to perform this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[self showActivityView:NO]
```

That will remove the sending view from the composer. Read it here http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the reference, I think that you can use the `TTMessageControllerDelegate`'s method [`composeController:didSendFields:`](http://api.three20.info/protocol_t_t_message_controller_delegate-p.php#a2829ad907cea2d4ecdb71961bdb2da66) to simply not skip sending the message when needed.

Comment: But then of course you must provide custom feedback to the user, because he/she expects the message to be sent when hitting _Send_.